# mouse move in python video game

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, ctypes

This code causes my screen to go black

I am using PIL imagegrab to process images

whenever i make a call to move the mouse using the following code the screen goes black:

```
def MoveMouse(x, y):
    extra = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
    ii_ = Input_I()
    x = int(x*(65536/ctypes.windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(0))+1)
    y = int(y*(65536/ctypes.windll.user32.GetSystemMetrics(1))+1)
    ii_.mi = MouseInput(x, y, 0, 0x0001 | 0x8000, 1, ctypes.pointer(extra))
    x = Input(ctypes.c_ulong(0), ii_)
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.pointer(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had that problem and it took WAY to long to figure it out, anyway for me the fix was to change in the line:

```
ii_.mi = MouseInput(x, y, 0, 0x0001 | 0x8000, 1, ctypes.pointer(extra))
```

the fifth parameter (i.e. "1") to 0:

```
ii_.mi = MouseInput(x, y, 0, 0x0001 | 0x8000, 0, ctypes.pointer(extra))
```

hope this helps.

Comment: You have to provide more information on why it solves this problem (using documentation as support for example). Please read [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)