# Python Move Mouse in Active window

Tags: python, mouse

Firstly, there are a couple of similar questions posted on this. But they are not complete questions, and no one has really answered them all.  I am using Python to send input to a game active in widow modes using "ctypes" package. The original idea is mentioned [here](https://pythonprogramming.net/direct-input-game-python-plays-gta-v/)

In particular, my codes are:

```
x=500
y=400

for i in range(10):
   time.sleep(4)
     if i > 0:
        x=x+17
        pos=(x,y)
    #ctypes.windll.user32.SetCursorPos(x,y) # this does not work in game but 
    #outside the game window
    ctypes.windll.user32.mouse_event(0,x,y,0,0)
print i
```

In order for the "mouse_event" to work, I tried inputting hexadecimal values but can't get it to move consistently. I tried setting up separate class & functions to import, then calling the function.  The function works outside the game window but not inside the game window.

The separate class & functions are based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43810203/mouse-move-in-python-video-game)

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Is it a bot that you're trying to make? You can try using [pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which is fairly simpler.

Comment: Just trying to play around first, pytautogui does not work on directx input requirement per the link in my question. Thank you.